# Why is unserialize nested inside another unserialize function in Wordpress core?

Tags: php, wordpress, serialization, recursion

I was looking through the Wordpress core, and I found this function:

```
function unserialize ( $data ) {
    return unserialize( $data );
}
```

First off, I don't even understand why unserialize has been defined since its a native php function.  Secondly, what in the world is going on here since its defined recursively without any condition to halt infinite recursion?

Throw me a bone.  I'm newbie at this stuff.

Comment: Is that function within a class or standalone?

Comment: That's got to be a method definition in a class.

Comment: My standard snarky comment is that you should not question how wordperss works. Down that road lies madness.

Comment: My guess is that the method would return the native php function result rather than call itself recursively

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's got to be method definition in a class, eg:

```
class SomeClass
{
    function unserialize($data) 
    { 
        return unserialize($data);
    }

    // ...
}
```

Otherwise you'd get a fatal error saying that you can't redeclare `unserialize()`.

All it does is add an `unserialize()` method  to a class. This method then calls the native `unserialize()` function in PHP. Seems rather silly, but then, I didn't write Wordpress.

---

I believe I found the method in question: [`wp-includes/rss.php`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/trunk/wp-includes/rss.php) (line 783). And it's indeed a method of the `RSSCache` class.

I suppose it's possible they might want to write their own serialization routine in the future and/or some subclass of `RSSCache` has its own `serialize()` and `unserialize()`.

Comment: The plan for future custom serialization is probably the most likely scenario.  It's been there since December 19th 2004, according to Trac, and was included in the initial addition of the file. (Again, according to Trac)  The rationale may well be lost to the sands of time.

Comment: Thanks folks.  Those of you that guessed class definition were right.  I didn't realize it but there's the start of a class definition several lines up from the unserialize function code.  So this is a class method that's being used to call the native function.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

NullUserException has it right. As far as an explanation goes, here's my best shot.

For example, let's say one day PHP decides to deprecate the unserialize function. Suddenly you have to change everywhere you can find "unserialize()" in your code to a new function name, and possibly do some rewriting. However, if you use your own function such as the way WordPress does, all you have to do is change your version of the unserialize function once and not everywhere it is used.

Comment: So they rewrote all the native php functions ? :)

Comment: They must have forgotten all the other php functions too!